# XPS Print Quality C# vs. XPS viewer

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, printing

I'm having a somewhat odd print quality problem in my C# application. I have an XPS file (it's basically just a 1 page image, that was originally a scanned black and white image) that I'm trying to print to an IBM InfoPrint Mainframe driver via a C# application. I've printed to numerous other print drivers and never had a problem, but this driver gives me terrible quality with the AFP file it creates. If I open the same file in the Microsoft XPS viewer application and print to the same driver, the quality looks fine.

Trying to work though the problem I've tried 3 or 4 different approaches to printing in the C# app. The original code did something like this (trimmed for brevity):

```
        System.Windows.Xps.XpsDocumentWriter writer = PrintQueue.CreateXpsDocumentWriter(mPrintQueue);
        mCollator = writer.CreateVisualsCollator();
        mCollator.BeginBatchWrite();
        ContainerVisual v = getContainerVisual(xpsFilePath);
        //tried all sorts of different options on the print ticket, no effect
        mCollator.Write(v,mDefaultTicket);
```

That code (which I've truncated) certainly could have had some weird issues in it, so I tried something much simpler:

```
            LocalPrintServer localPrintServer = new LocalPrintServer();
            PrintQueue defaultPrintQueue = LocalPrintServer.GetDefaultPrintQueue();
            PrintSystemJobInfo xpsPrintJob = defaultPrintQueue.AddJob("title", xpsDocPath, false);
```

Same results.

I even tried using the WCF print dialog, same poor quality (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742418.aspx).

One area I haven't tried yet, is using the old-school underlying print API's, but I'm not sure why that would behave differently. One other option I have, is my original document is a PDF, and I have a good 3rd party library that can make me an EMF file instead. However, every time I try to stream that EMF file to my printer, I get garbled text.

Any ideas on why this quality is lost, how to fix, or how to stream an EMF file to a print driver, would be much appreciated!

UPDATE: 
One other note. This nice sample app: http://wrb.home.xs4all.nl/Articles_2010/Article_XPSViewer_01.htm experiences the same quality loss. I've also now performed tests where I open the PDF directly and render the Bitmaps to a Print Document, same fuzziness of the resulting images. If I open the PDFs in Acrobat and print they look fine.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have anything helpful in terms of a solution for you, but your post mentions, and is tagged WCF.  I believe this should be WPF, not WCF.  Changing it might make your post more visible to someone who does have an answer for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So to close this issue, it seems that the IBM Infoprint driver (at least the way it's being used here) has quite different quality depending on how you print in C#.

In this question I was using:

```
System.Windows.Documents.Serialization.Write(Visual, PrintTicket);
```

I completely changed my approach, removing XPS entirely, and obtained an emf (windows metafile) rendition of my document, then sent that emf file to the Windows printer using the windows print event handler:

```
using (PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument())
{
    pd.DocumentName = this.mJobName;
    pd.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = this.mPrinterName;
    pd.PrintController = new StandardPrintController();
    pd.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(DoPrintPage);
    pd.Print();
}
```

(I've obviously omitted a lot of code here, but you can find examples of how to use this approach relatively easily)

In my testing, most print drivers were equally happy with either printing approach, but the IBM Infoprint driver was EXTREMELY sensitive to the quality. One possible explanation is that the Infoprint printer was required to be configured with a weird fixed DPI and it may be doing a relatively poor job converting.

EDIT: More detailed sample code was requested, so here ya go. Note that getting an EMF file is a pre-req for this approach. In this case I'm using ABC PDF, which lets you generate an EMF file from your PDF with a relatively simple call.

```
   class AbcPrintEmf
{
    private Doc mDoc;
    private string mJobName;
    private string mPrinterName;
    private string mTempFilePath;
    private bool mRenderTextAsPolygon;
    public AbcPdfPrinterApproach(Doc printMe, string jobName, string printerName, bool debug, string tempFilePath, bool renderTextAsPolygon)
    {
        mDoc = printMe;
        mDoc.PageNumber = 1;
        mJobName = jobName;
        mPrinterName = printerName;
        mRenderTextAsPolygon = renderTextAsPolygon;
        if (debug)
            mTempFilePath = tempFilePath;
    }

    public void print()
    {
        using (PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument())
        {
            pd.DocumentName = this.mJobName;
            pd.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = this.mPrinterName;
            pd.PrintController = new StandardPrintController();
            pd.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(DoPrintPage);
            pd.Print();
        }
    }

    private void DoPrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        using (Graphics g = e.Graphics)
        {
            if (mDoc.PageCount == 0) return;
            if (mDoc.Page == 0) return;

            XRect cropBox = mDoc.CropBox;
            double srcWidth = (cropBox.Width / 72) * 100;
            double srcHeight = (cropBox.Height / 72) * 100;
            double pageWidth = e.PageBounds.Width;
            double pageHeight = e.PageBounds.Height;
            double marginX = e.PageSettings.HardMarginX;
            double marginY = e.PageSettings.HardMarginY;
            double dstWidth = pageWidth - (marginX * 2);
            double dstHeight = pageHeight - (marginY * 2);

            // if source bigger than destination then scale
            if ((srcWidth > dstWidth) || (srcHeight > dstHeight))
            {
                double sx = dstWidth / srcWidth;
                double sy = dstHeight / srcHeight;
                double s = Math.Min(sx, sy);
                srcWidth *= s;
                srcHeight *= s;
            }

            // now center
            double x = (pageWidth - srcWidth) / 2;
            double y = (pageHeight - srcHeight) / 2;

            // save state
            RectangleF theRect = new RectangleF((float)x, (float)y, (float)srcWidth, (float)srcHeight);

            int theRez = e.PageSettings.PrinterResolution.X;

            // draw content
            mDoc.Rect.SetRect(cropBox);
            mDoc.Rendering.DotsPerInch = theRez;
            mDoc.Rendering.ColorSpace = "RGB";
            mDoc.Rendering.BitsPerChannel = 8;

            if (mRenderTextAsPolygon)
            {
                //i.e. render text as polygon (non default)
                mDoc.SetInfo(0, "RenderTextAsText", "0");
            }

            byte[] theData = mDoc.Rendering.GetData(".emf");
            if (mTempFilePath != null)
            {
                File.WriteAllBytes(mTempFilePath + @"\" + mDoc.PageNumber + ".emf", theData);
            }
            using (MemoryStream theStream = new MemoryStream(theData))
            {
                using (Metafile theEMF = new Metafile(theStream))
                {
                    g.DrawImage(theEMF, theRect);
                }
            }

            e.HasMorePages = mDoc.PageNumber < mDoc.PageCount;
            if (!e.HasMorePages) return;

            //increment to next page, corrupted PDF's have occasionally failed to increment
            //which would otherwise put us in a spooling infinite loop, which is bad, so this check avoids it
            int oldPageNumber = mDoc.PageNumber;
            ++mDoc.PageNumber;
            int newPageNumber = mDoc.PageNumber;
            if ((oldPageNumber + 1) != newPageNumber)
            {
                throw new Exception("PDF cannot be printed as it is corrupt, pageNumbers will not increment properly.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess XPS printout is in ECO mode for some reason. Is there option to select standart quality or Eco (e.g. with ticket)? I have similar problem but moving to EMF is not possible (I get XPS file and have to modify and print it).

Comment: Wow this is a throwback! Thankfully that entire solution was sunset a few years back and replaced with something that didn't need to go through an ancient mainframe print driver. Good luck!

Comment: There is `OutputQuality` property in `PrintTicket` but not sure whether it helps. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/system.printing.outputquality?view=net-5.0